# Pivot Tables / Cubes - Need to create a new member that categorizes values from another member

Tags: excel, pivot-table, calculated-columns, olap-cube

Working on some financial reports in a pivot table pulled down from cubes / analysis server. I'm trying to take a member called "fund" and categorize the values into a new field called "fund type" so I can aggregate certain funds together in the pivot table. For example, if fund = 101, it is a "general fund" account. I'm looking at Create Calculated Member in OLAP tools but not sure how to best proceed. (note: groups/sets wouldn't aggregate the measures for the member and I couldn't add more than one at a time to the pivot table; I need all of the categories to display.)

[Calculated Measure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Rp4.png)